# Apache tiles doesnt work

Tags: html, spring, apache-tiles

Can some one help me with apache tiles? I follow various tutorial but could not display the corresponding files.

spring-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="viewResolver"    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
</bean>
```

My /WEB-INF/tiles.xml

```
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="base.definition" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value=""/>
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/menu.jsp"></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="body" value=""/>
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp"></put-attribute>
</definition>

<definition name="hello" extends="base.definition">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Beign java guys | tiles interagion"></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp"></put-attribute>
</definition>
```

layout.jsp

```
 <table border="1" cellspacing="2" align="center">
 <tr>
    <td height="30" colspan="2"><tiles:insertAttribute name="header" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td height="250" width="150"><tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" /></td>
    <td width="400"><tiles:insertAttribute name="body" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr><td height="30" colspan="2"><tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" /></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

So when I execute the code, it only display the text inside the hello.jsp but not the content inside header.jsp or footer.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is fine but Tiles is not installed properly yet

Change Resolver and configurer to be as below

```
<bean id="tilesViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver">
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">

            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```